# how to append an hidden input value with base 64 string for ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need help, I'm trying to append a hidden input type to a form from an java script library responsible for applying filters to my image. With the onClick event I'm appending an input type hidden with the value of the base64 string to the form on the page. Then when i submit the form it should submit the data into the form data and the php should then convert the base64 to a img file and save it. however it doesn't receive the string, when I try to echo $img its blank. and therfore the saved image has 0 bytes. I'm not quite sure why because all i'm doing is appending a hidden value with the value set to the base64 string.

Script.Js This is the file responsible for applying filters to the image, this is after the filter has been applied I'm appending a hidden value to the profile.html pages form with the base64 string encode.

```
if( effect in this){
    this[effect]();
    this.render();
    var img_send = clone[0].toDataURL("image/png;base64;");
    $('<input/>').attr({type: 'hidden', id: 'fileroast', value: img_send}).appendTo('#output');
}
else{
    hideDownload();
}
```

PHP5 Upload script base64 string to img

```
<?php
    // requires php5
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/profile_images/');
    $img = $_POST['fileroast'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? 'default':'images/profile_images/default.png';
?>
```

HTML Profile.HTML Main Page Ajax Call:

```
      //upload profile picture
    function submitForm() {
      if(get_user != logged_username){
        }else{
        var d = new Date();
        var time = d.getTime();
        var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfo"));
        $.ajax({
          url: "upload_photo.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: fd,
          enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
          processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
          contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        }).done(function( data ) {
            if (data.indexOf("Invalid") >= 0) { 
                alert('invalid file type, must be jpeg, jpg, or png.');
            }else{
              console.log(data);
              var post = {"pic_location":data, "time":time, "username": logged_username};
              console.log(post);
              var json_data = post;
              Cynergi.insert('http://.com:3000/profile_pictures', json_data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
   }
```

HTML Profile.HTML Upload modal form html.

```
<div id="uploadPic" class="modal fade" >
  <form method="post" id="fileinfo" name="fileinfo" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background:#f3f3f3;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:black;">Choose picture to upload as profile pic.</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div id="photo">
                <a href="#" class="downloadImage" target="_blank" download="photo.png">Download Image</a>-
              </div>
              <div id="filterContainer" style='width:400px;'>
                <ul id="filters" style='width:400px;'>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="normal">Normal</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="vintage">Vintage</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="lomo">Lomo</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="clarity">Clarity</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="sinCity">Sin City</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="sunrise">Sunrise</a> </li> 
                  <li> <a href="#" id="crossProcess">Cross Process</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="orangePeel">Orange Peel</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="love">Love</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="grungy">Grungy</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="jarques">Jarques</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="pinhole">Pinhole</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="oldBoot">Old Boot</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="glowingSun">Glowing Sun</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="hazyDays">Hazy Days</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="herMajesty">Her Majesty</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="nostalgia">Nostalgia</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="hemingway">Hemingway</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#" id="concentrate">Concentrate</a> </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div id='output_file'></div>
              <div id="output"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="return submitForm();"/> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Http request inspector:

```
Remote Address:
Request URL:http://thewaywardjourney.com/upload_photo.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 05 May 2015 22:25:11 GMT
Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:44
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryWxBLMFLj0klea1td
Cookie:token=00; username=00; getuser=000
Host:thewaywardjourney.com
Origin:http://thewaywardjourney.com
Referer:http://thewaywardjourney.com/profile.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryWxBLMFLj0klea1td--
```

var img_send = clone[0].toDataURL("image/png;base64;");
$('').attr({type: 'hidden', id: 'fileroast', value: encodeURIComponent(img_send)}).appendTo('#output');

```
console.log(decodeURIComponent($('#fileroast').val()));
```

outputs:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAH0CAYAAADL1t+KAAAgAElEQ…P3PeerM0GN4J7vE4xyTdlT34hvfOMbuiYnL6xlqkUu4v8BZ033tp7lXCwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

console.log($('#fileroast').val());
```

outputs:

```
data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAH0CAYAAADL1t%2BKAAAgAElEQVR4Xsy9CbhlV1UtPPbep2%2FuuX1%2Fq29SVan0gUAU8AEJSYCQIEhoQoAISE9QQJSHIsIDBeX5sHkqSuOPD39EMCBBBRII6WlNX33VvVW3P%2F3Z%2Ff6%2FMdde5%2B57qkmQxPef%2Buq73Tm7WXutOeYcc8y5jK985HVRFEaIogimacIwDBimCXlFEbwwgGGZMA3%2BN4Awkt8b6h2IAARY%2Byz4nihCEARyLNOyEIVh%2FO5Tf0kZ6ny8Bv7ni9fC%2F%2FyZxwrNUH7mifkWK%2F6b%2FowVWQgjX66X7w9CA0cPH0eILDwXmNi8Ade86jo04aM8UEFtaQnpIETkBwgtYGRyAu2WjZQFZCxgZf44jux%2FGMOVMny7g1azgVJpFJ%2F57Jdx6x0%2FgZXvw5e%2B%2Bjl03BWEoY%2B0lQFgrbtBfS9rv%2BQ9yC3AjCKEBuAGEbL5EooDQwgiC0EYIGMAh%2Fc%2FAisK5L9pplDq64fjejBTakz0i2NsWRbCMITneciW%2B5Aq9cl9ZVIGUojQrtex%2F9GHYUUh0qkUpjdvhR%2BE8hm%2BeIzky5Dn0fu79T%2FzVvv6BxAZPIMJIwJatRWsLi7BDH24gSvzZmh0DH4UIjIsmAFgBKHMoSDivFJn5fPiPZVKJTSbTbmuRq2KoN3qXh%2FvrXeOBK4LNwiQr1Sw%2B5zz0OF7IgtGZMKMgNDg%2FZ157sUzHRHnPS%2FIsOD7PjL5AgrFIjzTAqIQBgLUV5ZRXZpHPp2C67Rgd9qYmt4CWOnunOU3elzXxtSEhxBWJotCqQQeLQpCWLA4cui4TawePwKvsQiurP7RDcgNjMBxHGRTBsxg7XmfegVZ4JNOvjie%2BrmGUYR0aZCTTv4bCOG2G2hWl5EKQhieA8%2BP0LQdTG%2FagMiy4Mo6B8z4H%2B8%2FNDxEBm2EJc%2Bcf02ls0il0gi4fs0IkWkhhImwVUVt9iBSkY%2BG7aJ%2FYjNKhdK6a0yOU%2Fdae2yFrPnEK%2BCzMHhvygaFbohMpoBiroKnXfIMHD%2B6H79%2B0xvxK9e9FAsrC0hl0zLmw6PjCCIDIZ9vEABOEwf2PYxde8%2BHb6RhhB686gJW5%2FYja0Sylnzfjc8cIZI7VDbKNDjWBhzPh%2B8H2LhpE1yXk9tEZACeZ6Ovr4RPfuyTeMbTnwUDGcxs2or%2F8fE%2FwsYd2%2BEEPtAJYTuOsmlWCpaVFltpe55azxFkXHkdHCf%2BTttFrhfXdZFKrX%2FmfI%2B2h5zDppkV28v38Rj8G79vt9tIp9PI5wtoNBrIZjPK7nNADdpbH5bFcY%2Fgug6KxaKcL2l3eBzX9ZBJFxCGaq5pW9S12XyWRgBeOs%2FP%2F7xfnptzm9%2FzmtPprBxf3WOIMFL2IJ22sGXrdnz%2BC19Dcont....
```

Here is my php:

```
<?php

    // requires php5

    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/profile_images/');

    $img = $_POST['fileroast'];



    function base64url_decode($data) { 

      return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT)); 

    } 



    $img_ret = base64url_decode($img);

    print $img_ret;

    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img_ret);

    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img_ret);

    $data = base64_decode($img_ret);

    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';

    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

    print $data . $file;

    //print $success ? 'default':'images/profile_images/default.png';

?>
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing the point, why not just use `<input type="file" />` ? This seems like a difficult way to pass the image. Also you might encounter truncated text. Also what errors do you get? When you use an HTTP reporting tool, what is posted in your request?

Comment: @Twisty I'm not using the input file type because you can't dynamically set the file with that. Also, this is the way im doing it because when a user drags a photo it they can select a filter to apply like instagram the image im setting to the hidden field via base64 encode string is the image with the applied filter which exist on a js canvas. Then I create the input field to store the base64 of the filtered image. That way when i send that base64 to the php it converts it back to image and saves it.

Comment: Ok makes sense now. One thing I noticed, the Content-Length is 44? I would suspect it would be higher, wouldn't you? Might suggest the data is not be posted properly.

Comment: yea i know its not getting posted properly i think Misunderstoon has it right.

Comment: Especially if a + or / is near the beginning of the string.  Think in terms of the Browser.  An illegal character is received.  What do you do?  There is only one answer.  Discard.   In FireFox Inspector or Chrome Developer tools you can see exactly what is received by the Server.  Chrome is clearer.  right click Browser window, Inspect element, Network Tab, Change "All" to XHR, submit data, "Form Data" Select  "view source".  It will show any data submitted in the AJAX HTTP Request.

Comment: Firebug and HttpFox plugin for FireFox are life savers for seeing this info and troubleshooting AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

base64 character set has a + and / so the string must be urlencoded.

1. Right click Browser window,
2. Inspect element, Network Tab,
3. Change "All" to XHR, submit data,
4. "Form Data" Select "view source".

   It will show any data submitted in the AJAX HTTP Request.

[image]

Comment: how do I do that and still have the php interpret the string correctly? I've posted my attempt.

Comment: Use Chrome, Developer Tools, see image in my update.